# How to see a list of web pages that have Genius annotations?

Tags: annotations

Genius (formerly Rap Genius) is [rolling out a feature](http://www.capitalnewyork.com/article/media/2015/01/8560211/genius-tests-annotate-everything-everywhere-feature) that allows one to annotate any website on the Internet by prepending `genius.com` to the URL. So far, it appears only beta testers are allowed to actually annotate websites with this feature, but anyone can read annotations that have been made with it.

See for instance, the annotations found here:

> http://genius.com/www.nytimes.com/2015/01/12/business/media/pop-music-critic-leaves-the-new-yorker-to-annotate-lyrics-for-a-start-up.html

and here:

> http://genius.com/www.vox.com/2015/1/13/7535561/rap-genius-new-yorker

But where else on the web are there Genius annotations? Is there an index?

And when will the public be invited to add annotations in this way?

Answer (score -3):

If i'm understanding, you're confused with how it works. The new york times article, is just a querystring. So that would be the same as like genius.com/?articleID=5     but instead of articleID=5 it just shows the full URL of the targetted article.

These indexes are all just saved on genius.com as their site handles all the querystrings and data.

Comment: But what's the list of pages annotated?